# Хранение атрибутов товаров

Tags: mysql, eav

Задача может быть тривиальна, но споров в сети много. Есть желание сделать свой интернет магазин. И встал вопрос о хранении неограниченного количества свойств товаров. Много читал про EAV, но как-то выглядит топорно и с поиском и фильтрами могут возникнуть сложности (не беру в расчет elasticsearch и пр.). Смотрел механизмы нескольких CMS.

Например, в open cart используется EAV, а для фильтров отдельные метки, что добавляет трудностей при администрировании такого магазина. У magento некое подобие расширенного EAV только я не понял как оно делает выборки, ведь для каждой такой операции потребуется сделать 4-5 джойнов, в зависимости от кол-ва типов свойств(int, float, date и пр.).

Понравился механизм хранения свойств в Битриксе, но я не совсем понимаю как там получить множественные свойства (несколько запросов?). Можете объяснить как лучше организовать такое хранение данных? Если не трудно, то с примерами запросов.

Comment: А какие сложности при поиске в EAV ? Это как раз та операция, которая получается у EAV лучше всего. Вот выборка всех данных о множестве объектов для него тяжелая операция (легко лечится дополнительным хранением всех свойств в самом объекте в json).

Comment: @Mike дополнительные затраты на преобразования типов из текстового в нужный(дату, число)

Comment: При поиске вам надо один раз сконвертировать заданные в разных типах значения в строки и подставить в запрос. Все. Во время выполнения запроса никаких конвертаций для каждой строки не будет. Будут только при получении данных, о чем я и сказал, выборка всех данных для EAV тяжело. На самом деле совершенно по другим причинам. Затраты ресурсов на конвертации туда и обратно исчезающе малы. Особенно это смешно выглядит при перечислении CMS на PHP. У PHP все драйвера работы с БД при передаче запросов в БД все типы сами приводят к строкам. (хотя в PDO это настраиваемо, но все принебрега)

Comment: Не знаю как насчет EAV, но на работе использовались 5 таблиц: категории, товары, характеристики, значения хар-к и отношения (relations) между товаром и значением. При чем характеристики привязывались сразу к категориям и оттуда попадали в товары в этих категориях. Соответственно в relations храним только idProduct и idValue.

Comment: @Mike Я имел в виду приведение типов самой MySQL. Например, что бы получить какой-то товар с конечным сроком, то мускул будет переводить строковое значение в дату, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: что такое "с конечным сроком". Если хотите сравнить с текущей датой, то вполне можно сделать `x > date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')` и он спокойно сравнит строки как строки и это единственно верный способ поиска, что бы использовались индексы

Comment: Кстати интересно, а какие там вообще даты могут быть в свойствах, хранящихся в EAV ? Все стандартные свойства, которые присущи всем товарам должны быть как обычно в собственных полях с правильными типами. В EAV выносятся только динамические свойства, которые у одних товаров есть, а у других нет. И среди подобных свойств дат обычно не бывает. Так что вполне можно сделать 2 поля - строка и число, причем скорее всего целого будет достаточно. Все таки числа лучше сравнивать как числа

Comment: @Mike Вы сталкивались с системой хранения свойств записей битрикса? Вот про это я говорю. Есть, например, свойство "дата окончания". Нужно выбрать элементы из промежутка. Мускул затратит дополнительное время для того, что бы сначала преобразовать строки в даты и только потом будет искать. И индексы не используются при выборки даты преобразованной из строки. Нужен тип DATE или DATETIME.

Comment: Не надо хранить так как в битриксе. Они там все пихают в EAV. В EAV надо хранить только переменные свойства товаров. Все что есть общего хранить в нормальном виде. Но если все таки дата есть и надо искать промежуток, то sql можно написать двумя способами `date(field) between X and Y` и тогда да, конвертация на каждой строке и никаких индексов. Но можно его и переписать в виде `field between date_format(..., X) and date_format(..., Y)` и тогда никакой конвертации и рабочие индексы. любой запрос можно сформировать правильно. главное что бы дата в строке была строго год-месяц-день

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAV архитектура позволяет хранить и обрабатывать большие объемы данных без проблем. Все будет больше упираться в операции чтения/записи при больших нагрузках на сайт, ведь при записи/транзакциях таблицы блокируются, если речь больше о чтении, то грамотная настройка БД будет давать хороший результат даже на чистой EAV. Конечно же все зависит еще и от объема хранимых данных, но и линейная раскладка от них тоже зависит. Более того, EAV после определенного размера дает более быстрые результаты, чем широкая и большая линейная таблица.

Не скажу на счет других CMS, но EAV в Magento как правило используется именно для хранения данных (считай для админки). 
Для фронта используется несколько дополнительных слоев, чтобы сделать его более быстрым и доступным:

- Flat index - линейная таблица, в которую раскладываются все значения,
  которые нужно использовать / отображать в листинге товаров, чтобы
  быстро их получать не делая много JOIN по EAV
- Attribute (EAV) index - это индекс фильтров. Тоже своеобразная
  раскладка с     всевозможными id опций ваших атрибутов + группировка
  для разных типов товаров
- Search index - для поиска обычного стандартного Fulltext / Like

Если у вас фильтров и/или товаров переваливает за некое значение, то тут уже MySQL начнет подгребать на любых таблицах и это не зависит от CMS. Решается либо переездом на более мощное железо, тюнингом MySQL, либо переносом каталога+поиска+фильтров на Elasticsearch / Sphinx.

Если же ваша цель именно иметь много свойств у товаров, но не использовать как фильтры, то еще можно поискать решение с поддержкой графовых БД под эти цели.
Уверен что модули для этого найдутся под многие CMS.